# Veracode CWR ID 80

Tags: java, veracode

and sorry to be a bother.
I am receiving a High Veracode vulnerability on the return from an endpoint. The endpoint is something like:

```
@POST
@Path("mydata") 
public List<MyDataObject> saveData(final List<MyObjectData> data) {
   return MyDataDAO.save(data);
 }
```

And I receive the vulnerability regardless of what I do. I tried to sanitize the incoming data, as well as the data that ia returned from the DAO. The only way I made it work is if the endpoint doesn't return any values. Does anyone have any ideea why it doesn't seem to work? Thank you in advance